# Flutter: Override pub package with a specific commit while retaining dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-html

We're having a problem with the `flutter_html` package in our project since upgrading flutter, but there's a potential fix introduced as a PR by other github user. The problem is, I can't get their changes to override the base package, namely because we also use `flutter_html_table` which relies on `flutter_html` to resolve its version with `flutter pub get`

Here's what I've tried using in the project's `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6
flutter_html_table: ^3.0.0-alpha.3

dependency_overrides:  
flutter_html:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html.git
    ref: 6908733505732bff93a5e7d45e822bd837c16c5b
```

But the changes introduced in the git commit I've referenced as a `dependency_override` aren't being reflected in the plugin's source code when I inspect it inside the project. This is after I've run a `flutter clean` to ensure cached versions weren't being used instead.

I've also tried swapping the git/pub.dev versions of the package around, but this fails to resolve when I build the project so I'm assuming it's the wrong approach.

I've also just tried running `flutter pub cache repair` to ensure the cache is *truly* wiped, but still has no effect on bringing the changes from the commit into my project.

Comment: The repository at https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html.git doesn't have any such `690873...` commit. Looking through the PRs, I assume you're referring to https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/pull/1191.  For that, you would need to use the repository for the corresponding fork (https://github.com/darkstarx/flutter_html.git).  Alternatively apply the patch to your own local clone of the `flutter_html` repository and use `dependency_overrides` to [refer to your local copy](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jamesdlin :) I've replaced the reference to use what you've mentioned there and it seems to be fetching fine now. However, when I run my app the problematic widgets are still referencing the original package rather than the package from the override reference. Do I need to change my imports to point to the git package?

Comment: I've resolved this now, thank you! Leaving my previous comment to help others find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the fact that `dependency_overrides` [only apply to the package that they're defined in](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides). As my project has multiple dependencies (app, core, types, etc.) and I was defining the override in 'core', the 'app' package (which depends on 'core') used the original `flutter_html` package instead of the overridden one.

Moving the dependency override to my app package's pubspec.yaml resolved the issue :)